# Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ going forward with probability $p$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, random-walks

Consider a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ which goes forward (i.e. takes a step in the same direction as the last step) with probability $p$ and turns right and left with probability $\frac{1-p}{2}$ respectively. Is it recurrent for all $1 > p \geq 0$?

Comment: this can be diractlly calculate by solve a equation come from markov property.

Comment: Well, on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ there is right, left, forward and back.

Comment: uh, what is the mean of turns right and left. it go through two lattice?

Comment: Yes, it continues the same direction as the last step or it starts to walk in a new direction.

Comment: This is an interesting example of a discrete time process, which is not a Markov chain. Of course it can be formulated as a Markov chain with state space f.i. $S = \mathbb{Z}^2  \times\{u,d,l,r\}$, with $u$ representing the upper direction, $\ldots$. The formulation of the transition law is a little bit cumbersome. I think that this MC is recurrent but I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like recurrence follows from Theorem 1 in Bender and Richmond, *Correlated Random Walks*, Ann. Probab. 12(1) (1984): 274–278 [DOI:10.1214/aop/1176993392](https://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1176993392). (It gets late, though, so I may be getting something wrong.)

If $X_n$ is the "random walk" described in the question and $D_n$ is the "direction" in which the random walk is moving in step $n$, then $(D_n, X_{n+1} - X_n)$ is the "correlated random walk" according to the terminology of Bender and Richmond. Thus, we have to verify three conditions:

- The "correlated random walk" is *drift-free*, that is, $\mathbb E|X_n| = o(n)$. This seems to follow from exponential convergence of the distribution of $D_n$ to the uniform distribution over four admissible directions.
- *Condition A* holds: for some $d$ and $d'$, the support of the conditional distribution $X_{n+1} - X_n$ given $D_n = d$ and $D_{n+1} = d'$ is a linearly dense set in $\mathbb R^2$. This deepends on the exact definition of $X_n$, but even if this condition fails, the "correlated random walk" $(D_{2n}, X_{2n+2} - X_{2n})$ satisfies this condition.
- *Condition B* holds: the Markov chain $D_n$ (or $D_{2n}$) is "strongly irreducible": this is clearly true.